# Batch rename URL encoded file name & folder path

Tags: linux, bash, macos, cygwin

I've some downloaded files and unfortunately the tool uses URL encoding in the file path. How can I fix it?

Few paths:

```
/tmp/site/test/m%3dplusone
/tmp/site/test/m%3dplusone/rt%3dj
/tmp/site/test/m%3dplusone/rt%3dj/sv%3d1/35.jpg%3f_%3d15099203492
/tmp/site/test/m%3dplusone/rt%3dj/sv%3d1/d%3d1
/tmp/site/test/m%3dplusone/rt%3dj/sv%3d1/d%3d1/ed%3d1
/tmp/site/test/m%3dplusone/rt%3dj/sv%3d1/d%3d1/ed%3d1/am%3dwQ
/tmp/site/test/m%3dplusone/rt%3dj/sv%3d1/d%3d1/ed%3d1/am%3dwQ/rs=AGLTcCOhuNhUv0siK0B4I8EcahYmZPyCaA/cb%3dgapi.loaded_0
/tmp/site/_/scs/apps-mozaic/_/js/k%3doz.gapi.en_US.e1PemSdvnM4.O/m%3dplusone
/tmp/site/_/scs/apps-mozaic/_/js/k%3doz.gapi.en_US.e1PemSdvnM4.O/m%3dplusone/rt%3dj
/tmp/site/_/scs/apps-mozaic/_/js/k%3doz.gapi.en_US.e1PemSdvnM4.O/m%3dplusone/rt%3dj/sv%3d1
/tmp/site/_/scs/apps-mozaic/_/js/k%3doz.gapi.en_US.e1PemSdvnM4.O/m%3dplusone/rt%3dj/sv%3d1/d%3d1
/tmp/site/_/scs/apps-mozaic/_/js/k%3doz.gapi.en_US.e1PemSdvnM4.O/m%3dplusone/rt%3dj/sv%3d1/d%3d1/ed%3d1
/tmp/site/_/scs/apps-mozaic/_/js/k%3doz.gapi.en_US.e1PemSdvnM4.O/m%3dplusone/rt%3dj/sv%3d1/d%3d1/ed%3d1/am%3dwQ
/tmp/site/_/scs/apps-mozaic/_/js/k%3doz.gapi.en_US.e1PemSdvnM4.O/m%3dplusone/rt%3dj/sv%3d1/d%3d1/ed%3d1/am%3dwQ/rs=AGLTcCOhuNhUv0siK0B4I8EcahYmZPyCaA/cb%3dgapi.loaded
/tmp/site/_/scs/apps-mozaic/_/js/k%3doz.gapi.en_US.gzO-5OVAi4o.O/m%3dplusone
/tmp/site/_/scs/apps-mozaic/_/js/k%3doz.gapi.en_US.gzO-5OVAi4o.O/m%3dplusone/rt%3dj
/tmp/site/_/scs/apps-mozaic/_/js/k%3doz.gapi.en_US.gzO-5OVAi4o.O/m%3dplusone/rt%3dj/sv%3d1
/tmp/site/_/scs/apps-mozaic/_/js/k%3doz.gapi.en_US.gzO-5OVAi4o.O/m%3dplusone/rt%3dj/sv%3d1/d%3d1
/tmp/site/_/scs/apps-mozaic/_/js/k%3doz.gapi.en_US.gzO-5OVAi4o.O/m%3dplusone/rt%3dj/sv%3d1/d%3d1/ed%3d1
/tmp/site/_/scs/apps-mozaic/_/js/k%3doz.gapi.en_US.gzO-5OVAi4o.O/m%3dplusone/rt%3dj/sv%3d1/d%3d1/ed%3d1/am%3dwQ
/tmp/site/_/scs/apps-mozaic/_/js/k%3doz.gapi.en_US.gzO-5OVAi4o.O/m%3dplusone/rt%3dj/sv%3d1/d%3d1/ed%3d1/am%3dwQ/rs=AGLTcCN8zpbBBFew5eMDpwxBKYKKSK8U4Q/cb%3dgapi.loaded
/tmp/site/label%3fnode%3d0%26group%3d1%26allgroups%3d1%26offset%3d0%26nbins%3d1%26attrs%3dCategory%2b102275%26irversion%3d620
/tmp/site/id%3fd_visid_ver%3d1.9.0%26d_field%20group%3dA%26mcorgid%3d700CFDC5570CBFE67F000101%2540AdobeOrg%26mid%3d49349141751585207132014752155379255530%26callba
/tmp/site/id%3fd_visid_ver%3d1.9.0%26d_fieldgroup%3dA%26mcorgid%3d700CFDC5570CBFE67F000101%2540AdobeOrg%26mid%3d49349141751585207132014752155379255530%26ts%3d1
/tmp/site/b/ss/global/search%3Fq%3Da1%2Cb2%2Bc3%2Cd%26param%3Dvalue
/tmp/static_assets/media/jammer/megamenu/content_spots/custom/2674305-createyourown%7e1.jpg
/tmp/personal/vt/data%3dNwqMUcvO0zp-zhtVWUbRaUuK8hKaosTsTcCU58fnwoZT5MKfrwefqzeUX84jI1IUbrkBAA7G0LvDFgsIDzCc69CTnzc8Aq4S2HX1r6Mx5VgYQuGShWuY2O0516KXD9a431pw9S06KZJs
```

These need to be saved to it's URL decoded path, like

- `%3d` -> `=`
- `%3f` -> can't be saved to ?, as no file system supports it, so it can be replaced to `-`
- There's space in the path as well, like `%2b`.
- and so on.

So far I could solve followings:

- Remove query string after file extension:
  `find . -name '*%3f*' -exec bash -c 'mv $0 ${0/\%3f*}' {} \;`
- Replace '@' character with following command. 
  `$ find . -name '*%40*' -exec bash -c 'echo $0 ${0/\%40/@}' {} \;`

I tried similar approach to rename / move directories, but it doesn't work as only the 1st occurrence is getting replaced.

`$ find . -type d -name '*%3d*' -exec bash -c 'echo $0 ${0/\%3d/=/g}' {} \;` (the `/g` or global switch isn't working)

The environment is macOS / Cygwin in Windows. As it's known `rename` command isn't supported by default in macOS. One lines will be helpful.

Please help and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `deurlname` utility from `renameutils` package ... It's available both for [cygwin](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Frenameutils%2Frenameutils-0.12.0-1&grep=rename) and [homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/renameutils#default)...

Then: `find /tmp/site | tac | while read line;do deurlname "${line}";done`

Also, your `find` is only renaming the first occurrence because after renaming the parent folder, all of its content will fail with `file not found`. So, if you don't have and is not willing to install homebrew/renameutils, try `find /tmp/site | tac | while read line;do mv "${line}" "${line//%3d/=}";done`

Also, doing the `-exec bash -c '$0 ${0/...'` you are single quoting the whole command, so if you try to rename `%20` to space, it will fail. If you wanna use it, double quote the filename as `-exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0/...}" {} \;`. Also, bash's variable substitution `${0/}` (with a single slash) replaces only the first occurrence, so use `${0//}` to replace every occurrence.

Or if you wanna rename all url tags at once using `find`+`sed`: `find /tmp/site | tac | while read line;do mv "${line}" "$(sed -e 's|%3d|=|g' -e 's|%26|\&|g' -e 's|%3f|-|g' <<<$line)";done`

I'm using `tac` to reverse the `find` output and avoid the problem of renaming parent folder before children.

Comment: The `delurlname` utility is life savor. Thanks a lot. I tried other approaches as you mentioned, but the mv command runs into some issue and error out with `No such file or directory`.